# Return DataTable schema beside data, in web service output

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, xsd, asmx

I write a web service using c# and it going to be consumed in a java application.

Simply I return a `Dataset` that has one or more `DataTable` in it. Output is in XML format.

Now the consumer need to have the schema of the output table to know the table and field names.

this is the webmethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public DataSet GetWorkTypes(string UserName, string Password)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("CNIS");
    try
    {
        if (User Pass is Correct)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("some query", "connectionString");
            adapter.Fill(ds, "theTable");
            return ds;
        }
        else
        {
            ds.Tables.Add("theTable");
            ds.Tables["theTable"].Columns.Add("Error");
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add("Wrong User Pass!");
            return ds;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ds.Tables.Add("theTable");
        ds.Tables["theTable"].Columns.Add("Error");
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ex.Message);
        return ds;
    }
}
```

How do I change my code to do that?

**EDIT:**

I expect the different output than this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetWorkTypesResponse xmlns="http://cnis/">
      <GetWorkTypesResult>
        <xsd:schema>schema</xsd:schema>xml</GetWorkTypesResult>
    </GetWorkTypesResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

I need something to be more descriptive.

Comment: FIrst of all, you should not be creating an ASMX web service unless you're stuck using .NET 3.0 or below. That's a legacy technology and should not be used for new development. You should use WCF of Web API instead.

Comment: Second, you are attempting to return a .NET-specific data type to a Java client. The Java client does not know anything about the `DataSet` class. Please don't do that. Instead, return one or more collections just containing the data.

Comment: I was wondering what the difference of Web API is, for a long time! thanks for clearing me up. So, is it possible to achieve my goal with web API?

Comment: Yes, though it would still not be nice to return a .NET-specific data type.

Comment: Thanks John! Web API is the best way to do that.

Comment: I forgot to say, using Web API, I've changed the return type to List. So it can be easily  serialized to Json or xml .

Comment: Good. I feel much better now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is the answer to my question that inspired by @John Saunders comment. When the web service consumer is a java client, JQuery or a non-dotNet client, this is not the standard way to pass .NET-specific data type like `DataSet`.

So I use the MVC Web API technology to get the job done! It is not necessary to force use MVC , but it gives some good features to generate help and documentation for the web methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can give him sample xml data that he would be recieving.For that just give the path of your webservice in the browser like this:

```
www.yourdomain.com/yourwebservice.asmx
```

you will get list of web methods in your service.click on any of them to call and give required parameters if any and you will get the xml data.

Comment: OK.  your right. but my problem is to return the schema as well as the data.